# LocalDB on a clean Windows 11 (sandbox) - SQL Server process failed to start

Tags: sql-server, localdb, windows-11

I've been fighting this for a few days now, with no success whatsoever.
I am trying to use a LocalDB mdf file as my database for an offline AspNetCore application.
The feature looks so promising (A simple connection string switch in appsettings.json between full blown SqlServer+IIS for online users and a LocalDB+kestrel for offline versions...)
All works great on my dev machine - but i have SqlServer Developer installed.
What I'm trying to do now is install and run my app on the "windows sandbox".
I tried multiple versions of LocalDB MSIs(2016, 2019, 2022) - ALL produce the same result -
When I run "`sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB`" the result is
"

```
Start of LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" failed because of the following error:
Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.
```

"

I deleted, recreated, stopped, and around again... all the while using the (great!) feature of doing it every time on a fresh clean Windows11, But the result is EXACTLY the same every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're having this much trouble getting LocalDB working, I would have given up two days ago and just installed a proper instance of Express or Developer Edition.

Comment: Anything in the Event Log Viewer about the service start failure? If I were a betting person I'd be betting on the system volume emulating an SSD with sectors larger than 4KiB, ref: [Troubleshoot errors related to system disk sector size greater than 4 KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size). Try installing onto a volume with 4KiB sectors (or smaller) - this could even be a .vhdx file mapped as a drive.

Comment: The "sandbox" may be your issue then. Will your app be expected to run on the sandbox? While you mentioned on your dev machine you "have SqlServer Developer installed", have you installed and used localdb successfully on the dev machine / is there any issue with doing so?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, this is planned to be installed on multiple machines, and not by a specialized technician, so i figured a full sql server installation is not possible.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, read about this possible problem in my searches...did both testing the drive's sectors - resulted in 4096 bytes - which IS compatible with sql, AND adding the override key in the registry - didnt make any change

Comment: @Sean, re-using LocalDb on My (dev) machine, i did need to delete and re-create the instance for it to work (after installing the SqlLocalDB.msi). but besides that all working fine. dont have an  extra "physical" pc to see if it's "windows sandbox" related

Comment: When, trying to, install  "LocalDB MSI2019"  I get a failed to start "SQL Server VSS Writer", which stops the installation.

Comment: @Luuk - crossed that bridge... you need to install vc_redist.x86 AND vc_redist.x64 (2015-2019). this solves the install break

Comment: Anyone trying to help out - thanx a lot - i would still like it to be solved for windows sandbox, but for now i managed to get hold of a windows 10 "physical" pc, installed it all and it works like a charm!!! (so it's either the "sandbox" or "windows11" or both)

Comment: Please check: [Cannot start SqlLocalDB instance with my Windows account](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30383/cannot-start-sqllocaldb-instance-with-my-windows-account)